# Installing linux-headers-2.6.32-042stab085.20

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install virtualbox-4.3 on a VPS hosting which has Ubuntu 12.04 and kernel version :

```
uname -r ==> 2.6.32-042stab085.20
```

When I try to install it, I get the following error:

```
Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMSError! Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.32-042stab085.20 cannot be found. Please install the linux-headers-2.6.32-042stab085.20 package,
```

I know that the kernel is old and I really can't update it, unfortunately, since I don't have the rights for that... Is there a way to install the headers for this kernel version ?

**Edit1: I have found the following in /lib/modules/$(uname -r)**

```
/lib/modules$ cd /lib/modules/$(uname -r)
/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab085.20$ ls
modules.alias      modules.ccwmap  modules.dep.bin  modules.ieee1394map  modules.isapnpmap  modules.pcimap    modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin
modules.alias.bin  modules.dep     modules.devname  modules.inputmap     modules.ofmap      modules.seriomap  modules.symbols  modules.usbmap
```

It is strange though, since there is no include folder...

Comment: Why the downvote, can you tell me what information more you need ?

Comment: You are probably getting downvotes because 1) VirtualBox is not considered a robust enough virtualization solution for enterprise use and 2) installing VirtualBox on a machine that is already virtualized runs counter to many best practices. People shouldn't downvote questions because they are off-topic (see [professional capacity)](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) Bad Ideas (TM) but we so many these days it is the only way to keep the front page clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, it looks like you're trying to compile the Virtualbox kernel modules under an OpenVZ kernel?

Due to the way that OpenVZ operates, I do not believe that this is possible.